# NodeJS: How to generate all previous cached requests automatically on expiration

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching

I'm building a Blog API using Nodejs and my data coming from a scraping service that scraped data from multiples news websites live, so there's no database.

The scraping service takes around 30 seconds to return a response for page 1 of all sites I scraping with. ( Imagin with me how pagination will be looks like in my app :( )

> **If you don't know what scaping is just thinking of it as multiple APIs**
>   **and I get data from each one then combine all in one results array.**

So because of the long response time, I start using the `node-cache` package for caching and it saves my request time from 30 seconds to 6 milliseconds ( Wooow right? )

**The problem is when my cache gets expired after x time, I need to wait for a random user to hit my endpoint again to regenerate the cache again with the new data and he will wait for the whole 30 seconds until he gets a response.**

**I need to avoid that as much as I could, so any Ideas? I have searched a lot and not getting any useful results!!, All articles talk about how to cache not techniques.**

## #Update

I have found kinda a solution the package I'm using for caching provided in their API Documentation an event called `cache.on('expired', cb)` means I can listen to any cache get expired.

What I have done is kinda an endless loop making the request to my self every time a cache get expired

The code

```
class MyScraperService {
   constructor() {

        this.cache = new NodeCache({ stdTTL: 30, checkperiod: 5, useClones: false });
        this.cache.on('expired', (key: string, data: Article[]) => {
            console.log('key: ', key);
            // send a request to get all my articless again and again once the cahce get expires 
            this.articles( key.charAt( key.length -1 ) ); // page number 
        });
    }


    async articles(page: string): Promise<Article[]> {
        // nodeCache()


        if (this.cache.get(`articles_page_${page}`)) {

            let all: Article[] = this.cache.get(`articles_page_${page}`); //.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5); 
            return all.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
        }

        let artilces: any = await Promise.all([
            this.xxScraper(page),
            this.xxScraper(page),
            this.xxScraper(page),
            this.xxScraper(page),
            this.xxScraper(page),
            this.xxScraper(page),
            this.xxScraper(page),
            this.xxScraper(page),
            this.xxScraper(page),
            this.xxScraper(page)
        ]);

        let all: Article[] = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < artilces.length; i++) {
            const article = artilces[i];

            all.push(...article);
        }


        this.cache.set(`articles_page_${page}`, all);

        all = all.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

        return all;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to schedule a cronjob to call your **scraper** every `[cachingTime-scrapExecutionTime]`(in this case, 30) seconds with [cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron).

I would also suggest you to increase the caching request to above 1m, which will divide the number of requests to the other websites.

Comment: I have updated the question, see my solution and tell me your opinion about it.